Translating XBOX 360 controller input to XBOX one controller
recently i have bought a generic gamepad that is suitable for both pc and mobile devices. the gamepad poses itself as an XBOX 360 controller and for the most part seems to work perfectly fine with pc game. it uses a wireless USB dongle to work with pc and by using an OTG adapter it can work on mobile phones.
the main problem is with mobile games as some of them seem to only support certain gamepads (like PS5 and XBOX one controller) and do not detect my gamepad as a viable one.
i wanted to seek advice on whether it is a doable task to build an Arduino adapter that can translate my gamepad's inputs so it can mimic an XBOX one controller and possibly work with games like CODM.
i am aware of products like CRONUS and TITAN ONE but id rather build my own translator since i cannot get hands on any of them right now
(also that the translator does not need to work on the official console because the cryptographic bluetooth handshakes are hard to mimic and only has to register as an official controller to my PC and my phone)
EDIT: this is the code GPT came up with (since i dont know anything) any idea what is wrong with it?
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <NimBLEDevice.h>
#include <USB.h>
#include <usbhub.h>

// Define UUID for HID service
static const char *hid_service_uuid = "00001812-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"; // HID Service UUID

// Define Xbox One Controller IDs
#define XBOX_VID 0x045E // Xbox Vendor ID
#define XBOX_PID 0x02EA // Xbox One Controller Product ID

USB Usb; // USB object
USBHub Hub(&Usb); // USB Hub object

// HID Report Descriptor for Xbox One controller
const uint8_t hid_report_descriptor[] = {
    0x05, 0x01,        // Usage Page (Generic Desktop)
    0x09, 0x05,        // Usage (Game Pad)
    0xA1, 0x01,        // Collection (Application)

    // Button Input
    0x05, 0x09,        // Usage Page (Button)
    0x19, 0x01,        // Usage Minimum (Button 1)
    0x29, 0x10,        // Usage Maximum (Button 16)
    0x15, 0x00,        // Logical Minimum (0)
    0x25, 0x01,        // Logical Maximum (1)
    0x95, 0x10,        // Report Count (16)
    0x75, 0x01,        // Report Size (1)
    0x81, 0x02,        // Input (Data, Variable, Absolute)

    // Analog Stick Positions (X, Y axes, etc.)
    0x09, 0x30,       // Usage (X Axis)
    0x09, 0x31,       // Usage (Y Axis)
    0x15, 0x81,       // Logical Minimum (-127)
    0x25, 0x7F,       // Logical Maximum (127)
    0x75, 0x08,       // Report Size (8)
    0x95, 0x02,       // Report Count (2)
    0x81, 0x02,       // Input (Data, Variable, Absolute)

    // Optional Buttons (Triggers, etc.)
    0x05, 0x09,       // Usage Page (Button)
    0x19, 0x11,       // Usage Minimum (Button 17)
    0x29, 0x12,       // Usage Maximum (Button 18)
    0x95, 0x02,       // Report Count (2)
    0x81, 0x02,       // Input (Data, Variable, Absolute)

    0xC0               // End Collection
};

NimBLECharacteristic *pHIDReport; // Global pointer for the HID report characteristic

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);

    // Initialize USB
    if (Usb.Init() == -1) {
        Serial.print(F("\r\nOSC did not start"));
        while (1); // Halt
    }
    Serial.print(F("\r\nUSB Host initialized"));

    // Initialize BLE for HID
    NimBLEDevice::init("ESP32 Xbox One Controller"); // Set the device name

    // Create a BLE server
    NimBLEServer *pServer = NimBLEDevice::createServer();
    
    // Create a HID service
    NimBLEService *pHIDService = pServer->createService(hid_service_uuid);
    
    // Add HID report characteristic
    pHIDReport = pHIDService->createCharacteristic(
        "00000001-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", // Example UUID for HID report
        NIMBLE_PROPERTY::NOTIFY | NIMBLE_PROPERTY::READ | NIMBLE_PROPERTY::WRITE
    );

    pHIDService->start();
    pServer->getAdvertising()->start();
    Serial.println("BLE HID Service started");
}

void loop() {
    Usb.Task(); // Process USB tasks

    // Create a dummy report even if the controller is not connected
    uint8_t report[8] = {0}; // Size according to your report
    report[0] = 0; // Reserved

    // Since there's no controller connected, we can send a default report
    pHIDReport->setValue(report, sizeof(report));
    pHIDReport->notify();
    Serial.println("Default report sent over BLE");

    delay(100); // Adjust delay as needed
}


Yes this is possible. Which gamepad do you have? Which gamepad do you want to simulate, which system do you want to connect it to, and how will it be connected (USB or Bluetooth)? For platforms that already support official Xbox 360 controllers, the easiest option is to stick with Xbox 360 protocol (XUSB) but change the vendor and product IDs to match the official controller (045e:028e).

@nondebug I'm pretty sure you wouldn't know the gamepad (it's probably some Chinese knockoff) although it seems to get registered as an XBOX 360 controller. PC Games seem to work pretty ok with my gamepad ( since most do not have any limitations towards what kind of controller you are allowed to use) but a few PC games and Virtually almost all mobile games have the said limitations about specific controllers. I would like for the arduino translator to work with android natively (and my PC) and I want it to be registered as an XBOX one controller and for it to connect with Bluetooth.

@nondebug I also wanted to ask whether changing the vendor ID is possible with arduino (temporarily and when the translator is connected) and if changing the vendor and product ID can change how my gamepad is registered across my devices? If yes then I suppose there is no need to remap my controller entirely for this purpose.

The vendor and product IDs determine which driver gets used. On Linux (including Android), USB Xbox controllers use the "xpad" driver which has an internal list of supported devices. If your device's IDs aren't on the list it probably won't work. There's no easy way to change the IDs on a device but it's something your translator could do for you. That would be the easiest option, a translator that switches the IDs and leaves everything else the same. Bluetooth would be a lot harder to pull off, but not impossible. Maybe start with USB and use that while you experiment with BT?

@nondebug do know you any special libraries for changing the VID and PID? i did some research and turns out there is a way to create a bluetooth device with NimBLEDevice.h and with that you can basically send the incoming inputs from the gamepad to your device with the onboard ESP32 bluetooth. i tried it one and it seems to work just fine with my phone for the first time and connected successfully although i failed to connect to it more than one time, it even got recognized as a gamepad by my phone but i couldn't test it.
PS. i edited the OG post to include the code GPT wrote for me.

Any framework for creating a HID from scratch will have some way to define the vendor and product ID. Don't use product ID 02ea, that ID is for pre-2015 USB-connected Xbox One controllers. Xbox One controllers aren't HID over USB, use a Bluetooth product ID if you are creating a Bluetooth HID. Bluetooth product IDs have changed a few times, try 045e:02fd. The report descriptor you use should match the one from the real device: https://crsrc.org/search?q=kMicrosoftXboxWirelessController%5C%5B
